# How to calculate LinkedIn Campaign Cost

Tags: linkedin-api

We want to get campaign cost from LinkedIn.
We have checked LinkedIn's API documentation but couldn't find anything

**What we want is,**

- **Yesreday's campaign cost**
- **Last 30 days campaign cost**
- **Previous 30 days campaign cost**

Any help will be admirable

Thank You.

Comment: Do you have tried the [Ad Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#ad-analytics) API?

Comment: yeah.. i have checked and didn't find any solution for that..

Comment: See the metrics costInLocalCurrency and/or costInUsd in the sample requeste here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#sample-request